# How to add doctrine entity manager programmatically from controller?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, configuration, symfony-3.4

I have a controller method where i added doctrine connection and doctrine entity manager programmatically to the `config.yml`.

When i try to get the entity manager i just added via `$doctrine->getManager('newManagerNameAdded')` Doctrine tells me that the entity manager doesn't exist.

I think that it is necessary to specify to doctrine to reload it's configuration but I do not find the way to do it.

Has anyone ever done that?

I tried to make a `cache:clear` after adding the entity manager to doctrine config in `config.yml` but it did not work.

On the other hand if I execute twice my method of controller, the second time doctrine knows how to recover the entity manager added the first time in the configuration.

```
$configArray = Yaml::parseFile($this->configFilePath);

// Si la connection n'existe pas, on l'ajoute
if (!array_key_exists($entityManagerName, $configArray["doctrine"]["orm"]["entity_managers"])) {
    $configArray["doctrine"]["orm"]["entity_managers"][$entityManagerName] = array(
                "connection" => $entityManagerName,
                "mappings" => array("AppBundle" => null),
            );
        }

$yamlUpdated = Yaml::dump($configArray);

file_put_contents($this->configFilePath, $yamlUpdated);

$this->doctrine->getManager($entityManagerName); // This throw an exception 'Doctrine entity manager named $connectionName does not exist'
```

Here is the doctrine.yaml file :

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    default_connection: core
    connections:
      core:
        driver: pdo_pgsql
        host: '%core_database_host%'
        port: '%core_database_port%'
        dbname: '%core_database_name%'
        user: '%core_database_user%'
        password: '%core_database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
      customer2:
        driver: pdo_pgsql
        host: '%demo_database_host%'
        port: '%demo_database_port%'
        dbname: '%demo_database_name%'
        user: '%demo_database_user%'
        password: '%demo_database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
      customer1:
        driver: pdo_pgsql
        host: '%waigeo_database_host%'
        port: '%waigeo_database_port%'
        dbname: '%waigeo_database_name%'
        user: '%waigeo_database_user%'
        password: '%waigeo_database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
  orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    default_entity_manager: core
    entity_managers:
      core:
        connection: core
        mappings:
          CoreBundle: null
      customer1:
        connection: customer1
        mappings:
          AppBundle: null
        dql:
          datetime_functions:
            date_format: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Postgresql\DateFormat
      customer2:
        connection: customer2
        mappings:
          AppBundle: null
        dql:
          datetime_functions:
            date_format: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Postgresql\DateFormat
enter code here
```

Comment: post the doctrine.yaml please.

Comment: Are you trying to add a new `EntityManager` by changing the bundle-configuration at runtime (i.e. in a controller-action)? This won't work as the bundle-configuration is being parsed and processed long before the controller-action is executed. It's not evaluated on-the-fly.

Comment: Yes i trying to add a new EntityManager by changing the bundle-configuration. I do it in an controller action. Is it possible to add it to the fly ? In the meantime, i'm doing a cache:clear to take into account the change of configuration but I do not find it clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I founded the solution.

I add the new connection and entity manager to the doctrine.yml configuration file and i create in my controller action an entityManager via doctrine APIs.

Here is the code solved my problem.

```
// STEP 1: Update doctrine.yml for add connection and entity manager
$configArray = Yaml::parseFile($this->configFilePath.'doctrine.yml');
$configArray["doctrine"]["dbal"]["connections"][$connectionName] = array(
            "driver" => "pdo_pgsql",
            "host" => '127.0.0.1',
            "port" => '5432',
            "dbname" => $databaseName,
            "user" => $databaseUsername,
            "password" => $databaseUserPassword,
            "charset" => "utf8"
        );
$configArray["doctrine"]["orm"]["entity_managers"][$connectionName] = array(
                "connection" => $connectionName,
                "mappings" => array("AppBundle" => null),
                "dql" => array("datetime_functions" => array("date_format" => "DoctrineExtensions\Query\Postgresql\DateFormat"))
            );
$yamlUpdated = Yaml::dump($configArray);
file_put_contents($this->configFilePath.'doctrine.yml', $yamlUpdated);

// STEP 2 : Create new entity manager via Doctrine APIs
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array($this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir'). DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ."/src/AppBundle/Entity"), false, null, null, false);

$em = EntityManager::create(array(
            "driver" => "pdo_pgsql",
            "host" => '127.0.0.1',
            "port" => '5432',
            "dbname" => $databaseName,
            "user" => $databaseUsername,
            "password" => $databaseUserPassword,
            "charset" => "utf8"
        ), $config);

// STEP 3 : Create database schema
$metadata = $em->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata();
$tool = new SchemaTool($em);
$tool->createSchema($metadata);

// STEP 4 : Make what do you want with the new entitymanager
```

I hope this answer will help someone who needs it the same